# Change image source based on choice from select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

For a website I am working on there is an order form where customers will be able to buy cakes, there is a drop down which shows the available options. What I am trying to do is when an option is selected, an image will appear to give the customer an example of what that type of cake would look like.

I've looked this up and by what I've seen the best way is to assign a value to the options of the image you want displayed. However, I've already assigned values to the options like so:

```
    <div class="select-style">
  <p>What type of cake would you like us to make for you?</p>
    <select required id="cake_type" class="cake_type" name="cake_type" onChange="changeImage()" class="options" style="width:200px;" >
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select One</option>
    <option value="5|Round Golf Course" >Round Golf Course</option>
    <option value="10|Oblong Football Pitch" >Oblong Football Pitch</option>
    <option value="15|Round Chocolate Sweetie" >Round Chocolate Sweetie</option>
    <option value="20|Round White Chocolate Sweetie" >Round White Chocolate Sweetie</option>
    <option value="25|Round Unicorn Cake" >Round Unicorn Cake</option>
    <option value="30|Round Drip Cake" >Round Drip Cake</option>
    <option value="35|Football Cake" >Football Cake</option>
    <option value="40|Yum Yum Cake"> Yum Yum Cake</option>
    <option value="45|Oblong Carrot Cake" >Oblong Carrot Cake</option>
    <option value="50|Round AFC Cake" >Round AFC Cake</option>
    <option value="55|Square 8 inch Cake" >Square 8" Cake</option>
    <option value="60|Oblong Cake" >Oblong Cake</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    
    <img id="cakeImages" />
```

Now I have got what I'm looking for working by creating the following function function:

```
      function changeImage(){
    let image = document.getElementById("cakeImages");
    let cakeChoice = document.getElementById("cake_type");
    
    let cakeImage = cakeChoice.options[cakeChoice.selectedIndex].text;
    

    if (cakeImage === 'Round Golf Course') {
        image.src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/E5AhG5GXwAEADwJ?format=jpg&name=small";

    } else if (cakeImage === 'Oblong Football Pitch') {
        image.src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/E5AhG5GXwAEADwJ?format=jpg&name=small";
    } ... and so on
};
```

However I just feel like this is a pretty bad way of going about it and it could be done a lot simpler but can't figure out how. Is there another way I can do this without having to change the values of the select options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this where you use a data attribute on the option element like below (except change the value for the `data-src` attribute depending on the image ID):

```js
function changeImage(){
    let image = document.getElementById("cakeImages");
    let cakeChoice = document.getElementById("cake_type");
    
    let cakeImageSrc = cakeChoice.options[cakeChoice.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-src');
    
    if (cakeImageSrc) {
      image.src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/" + cakeImageSrc + "?format=jpg&name=small";
    } else {
      image.src = '';
    }
};
```

```html
<div class="select-style">
  <p>What type of cake would you like us to make for you?</p>
    <select required id="cake_type" class="cake_type" name="cake_type" onChange="changeImage()" class="options" style="width:200px;" >
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select One</option>
    <option value="5|Round Golf Course" data-src="E5AhG5GXwAEADwJ">Round Golf Course</option>
    <option value="10|Oblong Football Pitch" data-src="E5AhG5GXwAEADwJ">Oblong Football Pitch</option>
    <option value="15|Round Chocolate Sweetie" data-src="E5AhG5GXwAEADwJ">Round Chocolate Sweetie</option>
    <option value="20|Round White Chocolate Sweetie" data-src="E5AhG5GXwAEADwJ">Round White Chocolate Sweetie</option>
    <option value="25|Round Unicorn Cake" data-src="E5AhG5GXwAEADwJ">Round Unicorn Cake</option>
    <option value="30|Round Drip Cake" data-src="E5AhG5GXwAEADwJ">Round Drip Cake</option>
    <option value="35|Football Cake" data-src="E5AhG5GXwAEADwJ">Football Cake</option>
    <option value="40|Yum Yum Cake" data-src="E5AhG5GXwAEADwJ" >Yum Yum Cake</option>
    <option value="45|Oblong Carrot Cake" data-src="E5AhG5GXwAEADwJ">Oblong Carrot Cake</option>
    <option value="50|Round AFC Cake" data-src="E5AhG5GXwAEADwJ">Round AFC Cake</option>
    <option value="55|Square 8 inch Cake" data-src="E5AhG5GXwAEADwJ">Square 8" Cake</option>
    <option value="60|Oblong Cake" data-src="E5AhG5GXwAEADwJ">Oblong Cake</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    
    <img id="cakeImages" />
```